# plotting cummulative BarChart in BIRT report

Tags: birt, bar-chart, clearquest

I will fetch data from ClearQuest. I want to plot 'number of issues' against 'Submit Date' over a period of time.

I need cumulative count of issues in y axis against 'Submit date' in x Axis. I want to display different types issues as group against x axis.

Ex:

We have below table: There are 3 types of issues (Type1, Type2, Type3), cumulative count of these 3 types need to be plotted over a period time(Jan, Feb, Mar).

```
                  Jan   Feb CumCountFeb  Mar   CumCountMar

   Issue Type1     2    1   2+1 =3       4       3+4 =7    
   Issue Type2     3    2   3+2 = 5      1       5+1 = 6           
   Issue Type3     4    4   4+4=8        2       8+2=10
```

So i need cumulative chart for above data in BIRT(Not able to attach image).

i.e I want to display values from columns "Jan", "CumCountfeb", "CumCountMar" in Y axis. And SubmitDate in x axis.

"Issue Type1", "Issue Type2", "Issue Type3" will appear in groups for each month(Jan, feb, Mar).

As per my knowledge Cumulative count functionality is not available with BIRT chart package. I am not able to think about creating cumulative column for y axis.

Can any one please help on this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this by using the function "Year to date" from a "Relative time period" birt element:

1. Create a datacube with 2 groups: "Type" and "SubmitDate" and a measure:"issuesCount". In the "SubmiDate" group, keep only "Month" level and select the output format as you like.
2. Drag & drop this datacube to the report, in order to create a crosstab
3. Remove the measure "issuesCount" from the crosstab, and drag & drop instead a "Relative time period" from the palette
4. Set up this relative time period as a "Year to date" based on the measure "issuesCount". See the screenshot attached
5. Preview the crosstab to check if your "Year to date" is correctly computed
6. Right click your crosstab -> Create chart view, and setup the chart as you like!

[image: "Year To Date" setup in BIRT]

And a sample:
[image]

Comment: Thanks dom. But the solution is not clear to me completely. Could you please tell me how to create data cubes??. Adding to my main questions, "I have created datasets for tabales from CQ. And I used some computed columns in the dataset which is binded with plot. One computed column called "usecase" is used for Y axis. Usecase column will yeild four different IssueTypes.". Thank you!

Comment: In the outline view of BIRT Eclipse designer, select Data cubes->right click->New datacube.  Set your dataset as "Primary dataset" of the cube, and drag fields or computed columns from the dataset to define groups and measures you need. Datacubes are required to apply complex time period calculations such YeaToDate, rolling months etc.

Comment: Hi again, I am able to create new data cube with required columns and able to create cross-tab with the same. But i am not getting the function "Year To Date" in Palette. I am using BIRT 3.7.0 version. Is there any version problem?? If so can you please tell how to do with Version 3.7.0? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, unfortunately Relative time periods feature have been added in [v3.7.2](http://birtworld.blogspot.fr/2012/03/birt-372-new-features.html)

Comment: Hooofff!! Anyway thanks dom. Your answer might be useful for people who use BIRT 3.7.2.